# E versus e when using scientific notation

Tags: education

When I was calculating pressures in different units, I decided to use Google out of laziness. First I tried:

```
1.013e-10 mbar
```

and received a result of:

```
 7.598125e-11 Torr
```

Then, I tried:

```
1.013E-10 mbar
```

and received a result of:

```
7.598124847e-11 Torr
```

Clearly they are close, but what is causing one to be more precise than the other? I was under the impression that they were synonomous notations for Exponent, (10E6) = 10^6. Am I wrong in their definitions or is it some kind of coding truncation? In case this is unclear, [here is the conversion page I used](https://www.google.com/search?q=1.013*%600%5E-%600&oq=1.013*%600%5E-%600&aqs=chrome..69i57.4935j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=+mbar+to+torr)

Comment: Interesting find. There _shouldn't_ be any difference, but apparently some mechanism in Google's converter discriminates the two.

Comment: You are using a capital E so it's viewed as more imperative/authoritative and yields more digits...

Comment: who knows wha t Google  is doing under the covers - here's a link the c stanard printf which can format using e or E, but as far as I can see, this is just the lower/case choice, there doesn't seem to be any deeper meaning as far as I can see.  I don't think this is a math question.

Comment: @user247608 - where is that link? :)